# What compatibility issues may arise when using a NAS vs a "normal" Windows file share?

Tags: filesystems, network-share, network-attached-storage, server-message-block, development

I'm working with a group of Visual Studio developers who are using a server that has "NAS" in the name, and I'm unsure of the specific file sharing protocol in use between the windows client and server.

Is there a list of known limitations when using a SMB based file share (that isn't based on Windows) and how that would affect file IO calls.

From an API perspective, there isn't much of a difference when using Win32 calls or .NET, therefore I am curious about the protocol-level interaction between the workstation and server.

**Question**

Can anyone provide insight into the limitations and bugs that could appear when using a NAS device with a Windows desktop versus a standard Windows Server?

Answer (score 1):

I have setup a few NAS boxes that are nothing but a bunch of disks and a network interface. Definitely not a windows server, they were running busybox under the hood. So the disks would be formatted using the ext* file system and sharing is done with samba.

This works ok if you just want to copy a file every now and then. But a lot of the metadata in the NTFS file system (permissions, owner, read-only, etc...) are lost when writing to a disk formatted with the ext* file system. So if that extended data in the NTFS file system is important to you then you will want to use something that formats the disks with NTFS, like a windows server box, or something running windows PE under the hood.